# how to find number of weekdays in array

Tags: java

i have an **array of date**. I want to find how many **weekdays** are in that array. So how can i do that using java..

> ```
> *here i read lines from csv file & put those into values. 
> *values[2] contain the dates of that csv file.
> *So now i want to find number of weekdays in values[2].
> ```

```
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("c:/sample.csv");
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while (bf.ready()) {
               String line = bf.readLine();
               String[] values=line.split(",");
               String date=values[2];
                           }
```

here is my csv file

```
11/1/2010,jhone 
11/3/2010,alex
11/6/2010,jhone 
11/2/2010,neil
11/20/2010,neil 
11/15/2010,jhone
```

Comment: can you post a bit of your CSV file

Comment: here i post the csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String input = "11/1/2010";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yyyy");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(input);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
boolean isWeekday = dayOfWeek >= 2 && dayOfWeek <= 6;
System.out.println(isWeekday);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the Joda-Time library.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dayOfWeek = fmt.parseDateTime(values[2]).dayOfWeek().getAsText();
```

You could then do some comparison logic to check if the string is 'Saturday' or 'Sunday'. Joda-Time API also allows you to get the value as an int which means you just have to check if the integer returned is greater than 5 (1-Monday...7-Sunday).

```
// int weekDayCount = 0; // initialise this somewhere.
weekDayCount += ((fmt.parseDateTime(values[2]).dayOfWeek().get() < 6) ? 1 : 0);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see you read them in as strings, but you didn't mention the format of the dates? (Like e.g. YYYY-MM-DD)

You should probably parse the string into a [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object (using [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)), and use that to set the time of a [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance. With the calendar you can easily get the weekday from the date.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Calendar class. It has the method that returns day of the week. You can then put a simple logic around it to figure out if its a week day or not.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html